# SQL Get value based on lowest value in other column

Tags: sql

I have a requirement in SQL where I need to get derive the value based on the lowest value in another column.

In this example we can see the lowest amount is 4,900,000.00 and the OrginalCurrency for this is GBP. So the value for the LowestCurrency should be set to GBP for this row only. The other rows are then set to UNK.

Are there any windowed functions that can help achieve this? I've tried FIRST_VALUE but not able to set the other "non-qualified" rows to UNK.

The expected output is:

```
OriginalCurrency    LowestCurrency  Reference        Amount
GBP                 GBP             2000001/001/18   4,900,000.00 
EUR                 UNK             2000001/001/18   7,500,000.00 
USD                 UNK             2000001/001/18   10,000,000.00 
GBP                 UNK             2000002/001/18   5,000,000.00 
EUR                 EUR             2000002/001/18   1,000,000.00 
USD                 UNK             2000002/001/18   9,000,000.00
```

Code sample here:

```
select *
from (values 
     ('GBP','GBP','2000001/001/18',4900000)
    ,('EUR','UNK','2000001/001/18',7500000)
    ,('USD','UNK','2000001/001/18',10000000)
    ,('GBP','UNK','2000002/001/18',5000000) 
    ,('EUR','EUR','2000002/001/18',1000000)
    ,('USD','UNK','2000002/001/18',9000000)) t
    
(
OriginalCurrency,
LowestCurrency,
Reference,
Amount
)
```

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both. (And most people here want it as formatted text, not as images.)

Comment: Updated with text and code sample

Comment: @Brian . . . You should take the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional logic.  If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by reference order by amount) = 1
             then OriginalCurrency
             else 'UNK'
        end) as LowestCurrency
from t;
```

If there can be ties for the lowest value, you can use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 ...,
 case when amount = select min(amount) from t1 then OriginalCurrency
 else 'UNK' 
 end as OriginalCurrency
from t1
```